# Why am I getting {"readyState":1} on the DOM rather than JSON data in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to have the JSON data show up on the DOM (it's only 49 items) but I'm getting `{"readyState":1}` instead. I'm doing this mostly to test that my code is working.

I know where the issue in the code is, I just don't know what the syntax should be.

So my question is what do I define `$scope.dogs` as to get the JSON data to show up on the page? I have `{{dogs}}` in the HTML within the `'mainCtrl'` controller.

Here's the JS file:

```
const app = angular.module('dogBreedApp', []);

  app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dogs = $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    });
  });

  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://dogdatabase-d31f.restdb.io/rest/dogs",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "x-apikey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  }
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The settings variable and ajax thing was copied and pasted from the restdb.io service from where I'm pulling my JSON from and it logs the JSON just fine.

I'm a beginner at development so I'm sure it's probably pretty simple.

Thanks!

Comment: In this call `$scope.dogs = $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    });`, what you want to show will come in `response` from the ajax response, isn't it? the "dogs" I suppose. is that right?

Comment: If so, what's the structure of `response`?

Comment: Yeah that's right. `response` logs to the console as an object of dog info so that's what I was hoping to get to the dom.

Comment: @Taylorg You should probably not post your API key (unless it's not a concern).

Comment: @Lex heh, good call. It's not really a concern but you're right, I'll fix that

Comment: Taylorg, the answer provided by @Lex explains pretty much the same what I was 
 going to tell you after confirmation of what I asked you (and you confirmed it). That should work.

Comment: @lealceldeiro yep! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using Angular's AJAX methods instead of jQuery's if you're going to use AngularJS. Here's one way you could do it. If you put the `$http` call in a service then you can return the promise and handle the promise resolution in your controller. When using controllerAs syntax as I have done here, you need to put `this` in a local variable because inside the promise resolution `this` will refer to the promise and not the controller, if that makes sense. For the output in the HTML I'm using the `json` filter so that it will be displayed with indents and line breaks instead of just one long string.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('dogsService', function($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.getDogs = function() {
      return $http.get('https://dogdatabase-d31f.restdb.io/rest/dogs', {headers: {
        'x-apikey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
      }).then(response => response.data);
    };
    return service;
  })
  .controller('ctrl', function(dogsService) {
    var _this = this;
    this.dogs = [];
    dogsService.getDogs().then((data) => {
      _this.dogs = data;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
  <pre>{{$ctrl.dogs | json}}</pre>
</div>
```